# PHP - What is the best method to check a file extension, as well as determine the true file type?

Tags: php, file, types, upload, explode

I am wondering what the difference between `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` and `end(explode(".", $name)`, as well as an appropriate method to determine if the retrieved file type is really the correct content of the file.

For example, what's the best way to sort a file that was named "image.exe" and renamed "image.jpg."

I've seen a lot of talk about MIME types, but it seems that method has been deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to read an extension:

```
$ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

The correct way to check if something is an image is to try and read it with an image tool, such as [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) or [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). GD is easier, but imagemagick is better at handling big images, such as one uploaded from a 12 megapixel camera.

If you're worried a jpg is really an exe, the only way to safely process it is to read it as a jpg and try to create a new jpg (typically resizing it at the same time). Gmail does this with image attachments.

Also beware a real jpeg might have some kind of exploit, so even if it is an image it is not safe to just pass it onto the user anyway. You really should resize it to create a new "safe" jpeg and then give that to the user. You could make a new jpg the same size if you want, but passing the original data on to other users is dangerous.

I wouldn't even allow an admin user for your website to access a jpg uploaded by a random internet user. It could be used to hack into the admin's PC.

Comment: Thank you! I'm working with a couple different types of images - and most likely some .mp4 files.

Comment: Basically you have to find software that can read every type of file you need to worry about, and use it to check if the file is valid. Or else you can trust the user not to try and hack other users... not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES["file"]["type"]` is supplied by the user's browser and hence useless for security.

The file extension, as you note, is easy to fake as well.

If you want to make sure an image is an image, the easiest way is to run [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) on it.

If you want to make *super* sure and remove any and all metadata possibly embedded in the image, use GD's [`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring) to copy the image to an empty canvas (but be prepared for a possible slight loss in quality.)

For other file types, there apparently is the [Fileinfo library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) now. It uses the underlying Operating System's mime.magic file to estimate a file's type by checking certain characteristics and "header bytes" in the file.

Comment: You can also just substr the first 60 characters of the file contents. There are only 3 possible values for jpg and 2 for gif and 1 for png. That's all fileinfo does, and it's not safe at all if you're worried about security. https://gist.github.com/abhibeckert/8166418

Comment: @Abhi that checker is nice. Re security - I assume you are referring to the exploits you mention - I'm not sure whether those are anything but a theoretical possibility, though. Are there any known image file vulnerabilities currently in any mass-market piece of software? Re-encoding the file will, after all, always come with a loss in quality.

Comment: "Are there any known image file vulnerabilities?" yes, there have been dozens of them in Microsoft Windows and Internet Explorer over the last several years. Other platforms have fallen too, though it tends to be theoretical then rather than in-the-wild exploits. You're right about the loss in quality, there's no good solution.

Comment: @Abhi I meant "known and currently active" - those things are likely to get plugged extremely quickly (although, yes, unfixed Windows 95 machines etc.) Yeah, it's a question of weighing your options - if you're a photographers' community, you may have to serve the original image. If you're Facebook, you want to copy everything on an empty canvas.

Comment: There aren't any known exploits, no. But that's generally always true. It depends who's uploading the image how much you trust them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just working with image files, then getimagesize() should do it:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

It will return the image type as an element of the array it returns or FALSE if the file is not a valid image.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of double extensions when using end(explode(".", $name).
Apache will read the right-most extensions if 2 extensions are given which map onto the same meta information. E.g. file.gif.html will be associated as an html file.

As stated above, the client-provided browser info is useless as a security measure.

Best bet - getimagesize();
As with everything, there are ways around it. A malicious code comment could be added to the picture that bypasses the getimagesize() check because the header is still valid

Comment: Your final sentence here is extremely important, and should be highlighted. I would give you a mark up for that alone, but you state `getimagesize()` is a best bet; which while it's ok; doesn't do anything to negate that code can be injected into a genuine JPEG, etc.